# What would be the one word substitution of the phrase "one who receives a donation"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have searched a lot and could not come to a conclusion about what should be the exact word :)

My guess is that the closest possible word for this should be "beneficiary", but there are other words as well.

Can somebody explain, what exactly should be the word and why?

Comment: Can you tell us where you have searched and not found the right word?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about *[donee](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/donee)*?

*Donee*, according to Oxford Dictionaries Online, is used in the matter of a gift, but perhaps it's the best option to use since a *donor* is one who donates.

Other options (though these are a tad boring): *recipient*, *receiver*.

Comment: Since it's a rare word, I think *donee* might work best in a context where it's obviously paired with *donor*.

Comment: Gosh, those were egregious mistakes. Thanks, @snailboat, for pointing them out!